# Is there a way to use a Python script output as Simulink model input?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I run the whole think on a RP4 so i wont have matlab installed on it. Its more likely that the Simulink model will be complied to C or C++.

Comment: I assume this means code generation using the embedded coder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check out the following:

```
# test1.py
print('5')

% echo.m
function exitcode = echo(a)
display(a)
exitcode = 0;
end

# BASH
python test1.py | matlab echo.m
```

## Note

I do not work with Matlab frequently, so I may have botched that portion a bit. The key element on the Matlab script is the [acceptance of CLI arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/456241-how-to-apply-command-line-arguments-in-matlab). CLI args for simulink [share a similar pattern](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/174419-pass-parameters-to-simulink-executable).

Comment: Might be suitable for a matlab script, don't think this will work with a simulink model.

Answer (score -1):

I am looking for Simulink soultions only. Running Simulink or the engine is not an option for me on RP4, as i mentioned.